# download-url of GTLDriveFile coming nil and even GTLDriveFileExportLinks coming nil

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I want to download the files from google-drive. I have fetched the GTLDriveFile objects from a drive. But **downloadUrl** property of these file objects are **nil**.

Googling more, i got that **file.exportLinks** also has download links. But that is also coming **nil**.

I used this code to fetch files:

```
- (void)fetchFiles {

GTLQueryDrive *query =
[GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.maxResults = 10;
[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
       }

- (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
         finishedWithObject:(GTLDriveFileList *)files
                      error:(NSError *)error {
if (error == nil) {
    if (files.items.count > 0) {
        fileArr=files.items;
    }
}
}
```

here **fileArr** has the files of class GTLFileDrive.

From Google-drive developer site, i got the following code snippet to download file using a parameter Url:

```
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [self.service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString: urlOfFile];
[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {

        NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
        // Do something with data

    } else {

        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

I need the urlOfFile to complete the task.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To get the downloadurl, which method are you using? you can try in try-it provided for files.get or files.list https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list to check whether you are to able to get downloadurl for that file. what type of file are you trying to download?  check these links https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads and https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/DriveSample/DriveSampleWindowController.m?#691 for reference.

Comment: To make the request to fetch files as mentioned in [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) needs an apiKey : **GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}** 
Now where i can find this apiKey??
In the GTLServiceDrive there is a property called **apiKey**, that property too is coming nil. plz help

Answer (score 1):

When you do your initial auth, you need to request the right scope - otherwise, you only get rights to list the files, and not download them.

Something like.

```
NSArray *scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopeDrive, nil];
authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                  initWithScope:[scopes componentsJoinedByString:@" "]
                  clientID:self.clientId
                  clientSecret:self.clientSecret
                  keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                  delegate:self
                  finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
```

You can see this all in my new Google Drive Picker

https://github.com/ConfusedVorlon/HSGoogleDrivePicker